# How to Scatterplot data from csv file in Gnuplot?

Tags: csv, gnuplot, scatter-plot

How to plot a second x-axis variable on a scatterplot (both x-axis variables need to be the same units!)?[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btcJq.png)

This is file .sh

```
   set multiplot
   set datafile separator ","
   set autoscale
   set title "r"
   set xlabel "Time"
   set ylabel "r"
   plot '22_2_trapel_total.csv' u 1:3 w l  lt 1 lc rgb 'red'  lw 1.5   title 'r5_z0', 
   plot'22_2_trapel_total.csv' u 6:7 w l lt 1 lc rgb 'red' dashtype 0.5 lw 1.5 title 'new_r5_z0',
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use multiplot and two separate plot commands. Multiplot is used to place multiple plots next to each other, not to superimpose them.  Instead use a single plot command with the two components separated by a comma. Because you are plotting from the same file twice, the second filename can be `''`

```
  plot '22_2_trapel_total.csv' u 1:3 w l  lt 1 lc rgb 'red'  lw 1.5   title 'r5_z0', \
       '' u 6:7 w l lt 1 lc rgb 'red' dashtype 0.5 lw 1.5 title 'new_r5_z0'
```